# MVVM WPF удаление нескольких выбранных элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `ListBox`со списком автомобилей

```
<ListBox x:Name="autoList" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Auto}"  
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuto}">
```

Есть коллекция, в которой находятся данные из БД `ObservableCollection<Auto> Auto;`

как сделать удаление нескольких выделенных в ListBox автомобилей?
для удаления 1 авто использую следующий код

```
public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {

            return deleteCommand ??
                   (deleteCommand = new RelayCommand((selectedItem) =>
                   {
                       MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно желаете удалить элемент?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                       if (selectedAuto == null || result == MessageBoxResult.No) return;
                       // получаем выделенный объект
                       Auto auto = selectedAuto as Auto;
                       db.Autos.Remove(auto);
                       db.SaveChanges();
                       OnPropertyChanged("HasAuto");
                   }, CanEditOrDeleteAuto));
        }
    }
```

Класс `Auto` выглядит следующим образом(таблица БД выглядит также)

```
class Auto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string model;
    private string marka;
    private int cost;
    private int maxSpeed;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Model
    {
        get
        {
            return model;
        }

        set
        {
            model = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Model");
        }
    }

    public string Marka
    {
        get
        {
            return marka;
        }

        set
        {
            marka = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Marka");
        }
    }

    public int Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return cost;
        }

        set
        {
            cost = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Cost");
        }
    }

    public int MaxSpeed
    {
        get
        {
            return maxSpeed;
        }

        set
        {
            maxSpeed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MaxSpeed");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

БД получаю таким образом

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Auto> Autos { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<Auto> autos;
    private Auto selectedAuto;
    public ObservableCollection<Auto> Autos
    {
        get { return autos; }
        set
        {
            autos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Autos");
        }
    }

    public Auto SelectedAuto
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedAuto;
        }

        set
        {
            selectedAuto = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAuto");
        }
    }
    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        db = new ApplicationContext();
        db.Autos.Load();
        Autos = db.Autos.Local;
    }
```

**UDP2**
разметка

```
<Button Content="Удалить" Margin="10" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Style="{StaticResource InformButton}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=autoList}"  />
```

код VM

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand => new RelayCommand(o => Delete((Collection<object>)o));

    private void Delete(Collection<object> o)
    {
        List<Auto> list = o.Select(e => (Auto)e).ToList();
        list.ForEach(auto => Autos.Remove(auto));
    }
```

Comment: Вам понадобится враппер на ваш `Auto`, который будет сключать `Auto` и `IsSelected` свойства. `IsSelected` из этого враппера будет биндится на `ListBox.IsSelected`. Либо можно попробовать передать выбранные элементы как `CommandParameter`...

Comment: @AGS17 в голову не приходит ни 1 реализации подобной обертки. есть идеи?

Comment: В смысле? Я ж вам описал... `AutoViewModel { Auto Item, bool IsSelected } `

Comment: Вот как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/34632944/5598926

Comment: @AGS17 я видимо что-то не понял в примере.
даже если я получу коллекцию выбранных, то как их из базы удалять?

Comment: @AGS17 там работают с объектами из оберточной коллекции. тогда у меня с базой не получается работать

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, вечером как приду домой покажу как

Comment: @AGS17, добавил. если что-либо еще надо из кода - пишите

Comment: В общем вам уже предложили второй вариант. Вам нужен первый?

Comment: @AGS17 да, нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня работает такой способ, разметка:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Name="ListBox"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Autos}" DisplayMemberPath="Model"
             SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Delete" Margin="5"
            Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=ListBox}"/>
</Grid>
```

В коде VM:

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand => new RelayCommand(o => Delete((Collection<object>)o));

private void Delete(Collection<object> o)
{
    List<Auto> list = o.Cast<Auto>().ToList();
    list.ForEach(auto => Autos.Remove(auto));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделал как у Вас, объект o = null, и только бросает исключение.
+ `SelectedItems` сколько не искал - не нашел, только `SelectedItem`

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr, `SelectedItems` - где вы его искали, если в разметке ListBox - то и не найдете, так как это свойство только для чтения и запрещено ему что-то присваивать в разметке. Но вот читать из него можно, что мы и делаем передавая его в параметре команды.

Comment: А `null` там быть не может, даже если ничего не выделено - просто будет пустая коллекция.

Comment: я заметил. но максимум чего я добился - это получить 1 элемент. если просто Ваш код использовать - он ничего не передает. почему - непонятно. именно что o = null. не знаю как так получается

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr, Покажите как вы воспользовались моим сниппетом.

Comment: обновил пост. listbox у меня такой же

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr, хм... А `RelayCommand` свой покажите

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59320/discussion-between-alexandr-alexandr-and-).