# При нажатии на элемент ListBox все выделенные элементы перестают быть выделенными

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

У меня есть ListBox у которого, в каждом listItem CheckBox,который в зависимости ,от состояния,делает его выбранным или нет,но при нажатии не на checkBox,а на элемент списка,все выделенные элементы становятся не выделенными,а checkBox стоят с галочками,как это исправить?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate > 
    <DataTemplate  >
        <Grid Name="Grid2" > 
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="MyStack" Grid.Column="0">
                <CheckBox Margin="2" Name="SelectMessage" Click="SelectMessage_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Покажите вашу привязку состояния `CheckBox` к состоянию `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Можете подробнее описать что вам нужно в итоге?

Answer (score 0):

Если требуемый функционал состоит в выборе нескольких элементов из списка, то я рекомендую вам отказаться от помещения в список чекбоксов и воспользоваться штатными средствами, предоставляемыми `ListBox`'ом. Я имею ввиду смену режима выделения (свойство `SelectionMode`).

Установите ему значение `Multiple` или `Extended`.

В режиме `Multiple` клик по элементу выделяет его, повторный — снимает выделение, на выделенность остальных элементов этот клик не влияет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В режиме `Extended` клик по элементу снимает выделение с остальных элементов, для выделения нескольких элементов требуется удерживать клавишу `Ctrl` или `Shift` (выделяет диапазон):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом список выделенных элементов можно получить из свойства `SelectedItems`, в том числе и через привязку, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670865/218063).

Comment: а чем вы такие гифочки делаете?

Comment: [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/)