# Как в MVVM получить выделенные строки DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как получить выделенные строки DataGrid в MVVM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121363/7568618

Comment: Передайте параметром в команду `SelectedItems`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670865/218063