# Множественное выделение строк в DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Подскажите пожалуйста, как используя mvvm в DataGrid можно получить список выделенных строк. При DataGrid.SelectionMode=Extended.

Спасибо

Comment: Передавайте параметром в команду `SelectedItems`, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670865/218063

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: @АндрейNOP Скажите, а как привязать кнопку, находящуюся на главной форме (окне), и DataGrid, находящийся на UserControl?

Comment: Просто добавьте в свой UserControl свойство: `public IList SelectedItems => innerDataGrid.SelectedItems;` и привязывайтесь к нему.

Comment: @АндрейNOP innerDataGrid - подразумевается тот DataGrid, что лежит в UserControl?

Comment: Да ............

Comment: @АндрейNOP то есть на принцип MVVM  в данном случае просто забиваем?...

Comment: Нет конечно, что за глупости? Это часть View

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88946/discussion-between---and--nop).